# Solution of a Laplace equation in 2 dimension

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ be a given Laplace equatio with $1<x<2$ and $1<y<2$. Suppose the given boundary conditions are $$u_x(1,y)=y, \ u_x(2, y)=5, 1<y<2,$$ $$u_y(x, 1)=\frac{15x^2}{7}, u_y(x, 2)=x, 1<x<2.$$
Find the solution $u$.

I know that we can solve a Laplace equation by method of separation of variables or in terms of polar coordinates. But how to solve it from the given boundary conditions. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to homogenize some of the boundary conditions:

you have

$u_x(1,y)=y,\;u_y(x,2)=x$

and the Laplace operator is linear.

First it will be much more comfortable to transform $x=z-1, \;y=s-1$

So
$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=u_{zz}+u_{ss}=0$
And the boundary conditions transform to:

$u_z(0,s)=s-1, \;u_z(1,s)=5$

$u_s(z,0)=\frac{15(z-1)^2}{7},\;u_s(z,1)=z-1$

Now substitue:

$u=w+z(s-1)+3z^2(1-\frac{1}{6}s)$ will homogenize both $z$ conditions for $w$ since:
$\frac{(\partial (z(s-1)+3z^2(1-\frac{1}{6}s))}{\partial z}\implies (s-1, z=0 \land 5,\;z=1)$

For $s$ check new boundary conditions.

$u_{zz}+u_{ss}=w_{zz}+\frac{\partial^2(z(s-1)+3z^2*(1-\frac{1}{6}s))}{\partial z^2}=w_{zz}+w_{ss}+3(1-\frac{1}{6}s)=0$

so now you have:

$w_{zz}+w_{ss}=-3(1-\frac{1}{6}s)$

$w_z(0,s)=0,\; w_z(1,s)=0$

$w_s(z,0)=\frac{15(z-1)^2}{7}-z-\frac{1}{2}z^2,\;w_s(z,1)=-\frac{1}{2}z^2$

So you remain with a Poisson equation with homogeneous b.cs at $z$ axis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one more related question: suppose that $u_y(x,1)=ax^2$ for some constant $a$. Then for what value of $a$, the given boundary conditions gives a solution for the given Laplace equation? I mean how to show that $a=\frac{15}7$.